# Opencart Show the flag country in reviews

Tags: php, opencart, review

### I want to show the flag country when customers leaves reviews

I did this:

- added a row in db table review called `country_id`
- in `catalog/model/catalog/review.php` in `public function addReview(` I added :

  - `, country_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_country_id') . "'` so it stores the user's `country_id` if he is logged in

Now how can I call it and bring the image flag from Image/flag and place in `review.tpl`?

There is a topic in http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=58425 where nobody could give a solution

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that You have stored the `country_id`, You can simply load the concrete country based on that id when loading the reviews (for each review, respectively).

When the reviews are loaded from DB, in `catalog/controller/product/product.php` in method `review()` the array of results is looped through:

```
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $this->data['reviews'][] = array(
            'author'     => $result['author'],
            'text'       => $result['text'],
            'rating'     => (int)$result['rating'],
            'reviews'    => sprintf($this->language->get('text_reviews'), (int)$review_total),
            'date_added' => date($this->language->get('date_format_short'), strtotime($result['date_added']))
        );
    }
```

Now You only need to load the country to get it's code for flag, so You could end up with something like this:

```
    $this->load->model('localisation/country');

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $country = $this->model_localisation_country->getCountry($result['country_id']);

        $this->data['reviews'][] = array(
            'author'     => $result['author'],
            'text'       => $result['text'],
            'rating'     => (int)$result['rating'],
            'reviews'    => sprintf($this->language->get('text_reviews'), (int)$review_total),
            'date_added' => date($this->language->get('date_format_short'), strtotime($result['date_added'])),
            'flag'       => strtolower($country['iso_code_2']) . '.png'
        );
    }
```

Now the `flag` index should contain value like `de.png`, `gb.png`, `fr.png` etc. Just make sure You type the right value to the flag images in the template and that You have the flag images with such a names...